# Regex between tags unless escaped

Tags: php, regex

I made a PHP wrapper around Pygments library that highlights code blocks. Regex used for codeblocks detection can be configured in **configuration** file. (json format)

It looks like this in json value:

```
{ 
    "codeblock_regex": "\\[pygments=(.*?)\\](.*?)\\[\\/pygments\\]" 
}
```

Which should look like this after it has been JSON decoded:

```
\[pygments=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/pygments\]
```

This is bad since it doesn't allow escaping, I want people to be able to do this:

```
\[pygments=lexer]some code here[/pygments]
```

And pygments to detect `\` and just ignore that block of code. I tried with

```
 "(^\\\\)\\[pygments=(.*?)\\](.*?)\\[\\/pygments\\]"
```

which should look like this after `json_decode`:

```
 (^\\)\[pygments=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/pygments\]
```

However, this just makes it ignore everything, even the regular blocks so there must be something i'm doing wrong. I'm nowhere near regex expert as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a rather tricky regex feature called a ["zero-width negative look-behind assertion"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). "Zero-width" meaning it matches zero characters of the input, "negative" meaning it succeeds only if it is *not* found, and "look-behind" meaning it looks backwards.

The syntax for this is `(?<!test)` where `test` is the thing you want to not be there.

In your case, you want to match a `[` but ignore it if preceded by a `\`, both of which need escaping, so you need `(?<!\\)\[`

So your regex ends up as (in PHP) `$re = '/(?<!\\\\)\[pygments=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/pygments\]/';`

According to `json_encode`, that then ends up as `"\/(?<!\\\\)\\[pygments=(.*?)\\](.*?)\\[\\\/pygments\\]\/"` in JSON. I think my eyes are beginning to go funny with all the backslashes... `;)`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tonight and inform you about results and whether it's working! Yeah, that's what happens when there are more escape signs than actual signs :)